# Insect ID Montreal, Qc Canada

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this bug in my kitchen, in front of my oven.
It has wings and moves quite slowly on the ground.

I can provide additional pictures if required.

Can somebody tell me what it is?

[image]

I have found an article on a local website that seems to say this is a carpet beetle even though it's written bedbug right bellow it.

http://www.exterminationmontrealbedbugs.com/insects/

[image]

Comment: As a general hint: everyone on the internet calls every small insect a bedbug, every brown spider a brown recluse, and every 3 leaved plant poison ivy. There is a TON of misinformation and wrongfully ID's species rampant all over the internet. Stick to well cited or reliable sources (e.g., .edu or .gov, websites, science journals, etc.). In general,  TRUST NO ONE 0.o

Answer (score 1):

Dermestidae, *Reesa vespulae*; wasp nest dermestid
http://pestcontrolcanada.com/5965-2/

Comment: Also, I find long-winded explanations of species IDs to be annoying. When the question is "what is this species?" the answer is two words.

Comment: Respectfully speaking, your proposed ID is not correct. I suggest you explore the genus *Attagenus*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70626/discussion-between-charles-and-karl-kjer).

Comment: https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3253/2597399688_b6ca9e1370.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it appears to be a Dermestid of some kind, but I'm not a beetle pro, and so I'm not going to weigh in on the specific ID.  Sometimes family is good enough, in my experience.  I merely want to say that in my experience, commercial pest control websites are not places I would look to for accurate identification information.  I'm sure they try hard, and some of them may have people on staff who know their business, but all too many simply cut and paste posters and photos from other locations, without regard for accuracy.  The common "Spider ID" poster that pops up in the US, which features Australian species, is a frequent source of irritation for me.